# problem using python optparse and lambda as a callback

Tags: python, syntax, lambda, optparse

I'm having a problem by trying to assign a lambda as a callback to optparse to handle the case where multiple -v's are passed to the app, which should increment the global variable DEBUG each time a -v is seen.

```
# globals
DEBUG = 0
(...)
def main():
[...]
    parser.add_option("-v",  action="callback",
        callback=lambda a,b,c,d: DEBUG += 1
        help="Verbose (-vvv for added verboseness)")
```

When this gets executed, the result is:

```
    callback=lambda a,b,c,d: DEBUG += 1
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea or alternative (clean) suggestion?

Comment: You should consider using argparse, anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda has to be an expression, while assignment like that is a statement. You will probably have to do it like this:

```
# globals
DEBUG = 0
(...)
def main():
[...]
    def increment(*args):
        global DEBUG
        DEBUG += 1

    parser.add_option("-v",  action="callback",
        callback=increment,
        help="Verbose (-vvv for added verboseness)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to define a normal function, because assignments can't happen inside a lambda (unless you do some gymnastics).

However, I would recommend a) upgrading to `argparse` and b) using the `argparse` [action model](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#action). The `'append'` action seems like it would be particularly useful to you. (Or rather in this case, the `'append-const'` action.)

Comment: Thanks. I guess moving to ArgParse just because of a small limitation would be too much work :-)

Comment: Actually, I'm with @senderle - argparse is awesome :)

Comment: @CaseyJones -- I understand. Just FYI, though, [`optparse` is deprecated](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html), so you may have to move to argparse at some point anyway.

Comment: OK, thanks for your suggestions. I will head towards argparse then! :)